# Fetch values from database

Tags: python, django, view

Good day, 
I'm not sure if my logic is correct or there's a better way around it,
but supposed that you've a model:

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    field_A = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    field_ = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

IS there any way to fetch the above fields value without filtering, assuming that you do not know what is in the database in the views?

```
def get_values(request):
    person = (must have the value of field A)
    domain = (must have the value of field B)
```

And those values must be of the current logged-in user only.

Thanks very much for help.

Comment: How your form looks like?

Comment: @AvinashRaj                                                                                           class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    pssword = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

Comment: How do you know the values belong to the currently logged in user vs. some other user?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. What values are you trying to get, and what do you mean "without filtering"?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid i can filter the latest with queryset.

Comment: @DanielRoseman trying to get and assign the stored values for the field_A and field_B to person and domain

Comment: Do you mean *all* the values for each field?

Comment: @DanielRoseman exactly, so in my views: person = will have the stored value of field_A and domain the value of field_B

Comment: But you keep saying "the value of field_b". Field_b is a field on a model which can potentially have many many instances. *Which* values do you want?

Comment: @DanielRoseman My issue is how can  I use this: person = MyModel.objects.get(VALUE FOR field_A) because i'm not getting the stored value

Comment: Well why didn't you ask that at the start? That has *nothing at all* to do with the original code you posted! And you still haven't said where those values are coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost completely impossible to understand what you're asking here, but here's a guess. If you pass in `value_a` and `value_b` to the view, you can get MyModel items for each:

```
def get_values(request, value_a, value_b):
    person = MyModel.objects.get(field_a=value_a)
    domain = MyModel.objects.get(field_b=value_b)
```